# Como definir um checkbox simples?

Tags: angularjs, grid, angular-module

pessoal gostaria de saber como faço para deixar o checkbox desse grid com um modelo padrão.
exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6JRMoKQoirf23q1JlgR?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sempre poste o código aqui também, mesmo que esteja em sites para este fim especifico.

Comment: Como assim um modelo padrão? seja um pouco mais especifico.

Comment: coloquei um exemplo

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer pra mudar isso? Você tem que obrigatoriamente usar essa lib `ui-grid`? Você pode montar uma grid do jeito que você quer com bootstrap e um pouco de js.